# Laravel eloquent get order with current status using pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a situation to access orders have current status:  slug= "new"

Here is the scenario:

1. Table **Statuses**: with cols [id,title,slug]
2. Pivot **Order_Status**: with cols [id, order_id,status_id]
3. Table **Orders**: with cols [id, priority,client_id,...]

Where,
1 order can have many statuses

> Now I want to get all the orders where the last status of that order
>   is "new"

I am not clear if I should use the status model to get all order or get orders and apply scope.

```
$status = Status::where('slug','new')->first();
$orders = $status->orders()->?
```

or should do something like this:

```
$status = Status::where('slug','new')->first();
$orders = Order::withCurrentStatus($status->id)->?
```

**?** means I don't know how to complete this also what should be in scope function.

> I have to use eloquent not custom raw query.

I shall be thankful if someone can guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a condition on your eager loading query

```
 $statuses = Status::where('slug', 'new')
    ->with([
        "orders" => function ($query) {
            $query->where('some_column', '=', 'possible-value'); // single condition 
                                                 //or you can also pass array on ->where()
        }
    ])->get();

// dd($statuses); -> you can then loop through statuses and get each 
//                     orders by $status->orders
```

If you don't have any conditions on your `orders`, you just simply eager load it

```
$statuses = Status::where('slug', 'new')->with('orders')->get();
```

Comment: I have tried these conditions earlier but failed. As I want to get the order with the latest status = 'new'. However, with the condition you are referring to will get all the orders that have status = 'new'. no matter if its last or first.

Comment: Therefore, I have made an order status history table separate and add current_status to order table itself. to make it much easier.

Comment: If you mean, you want to get the latest order on which its status slug='new', then you can just simply do `Status::where('slug', 'new')->with('orders')->latest()->first();`